# Softlayer API: Account association?

Tags: api, account, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, associate

Now I'm developing a project about softlayer api, I wan't create a child account by call softlayer api. Then I will associate the child account with major account by call softlayer api. And destroy the child account by aoftlayer api.

So there is three questions follow:

1. How can I create a softlayer account by softlayer api ?
2. How can I associate the child account with major account by softlayer api ?
3. How can I destroy the child account by softlayer api ?

regards~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SoftLayer_Brand service is the one needed to create new Accounts.
In order to successfully create a new Account you need a BAP account, which are accounts for branding usage, if you haven’t got any, I suggest you to contact Sales department and ask for one.

You can create a Brand Account in this way using REST:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Brand/$brandId/createCustomerAccount.json

Method: POST
Body:
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "brandId": 2,
      "companyName": "test-571-companyname",
      "firstName": "test-571-firstname",
      "lastName": "test-571-lastname",
      "address1": "4444 Alpha Rd",
      "postalCode": "75244-4608",
      "city": "Dallas",
      "state": "TX",
      "country": "US",
      "officePhone": "281.714.3333",
      "email": "test-571-email@softlayer.com",
      "lateFeeProtectionFlag": true,
      "claimedTaxExemptTxFlag": false,
      "allowedPptpVpnQuantity": 1,
      "isReseller": 0,
      "accountStatusId": 1001 
    }
  ]
}
```

You can create a sub brand in this way using REST:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Brand/createObject.json

Method: POST
Body:
{
 "parameters": [
     {
       "longName": "Company Long Name02",
       "name": "Company Name02",
       "keyName": "KEY_NAME_Marce",
       "account": {
         "address1": "4444 Alpha Rd",
         "city": "Dallas",
         "companyName": "companyname02",
         "country": "US",
         "email": "test-571-email@softlayer.com",
         "firstName":"firstname",
         "lastName": "lastname",
         "officePhone": "281.714.3333",
         "postalCode": "75244-4608",
         "state": "TX"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: Regarding how associate a child account with a major account, it would be accomplished creating a child brand and then creating accounts for that child brand.

Additionally, I suggest you to read the next links for further information:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Brand
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account